Asian woman cuts off her own fingers while cooking
I don't have much information about this movie, unfortunately. I am pretty sure it was a Japanese horror film, and it was probably made sometime in or after the late 90s.
In the scene a women is cooking food while talking to someone. I think it was her husband. When the other person walks away, she begins chopping something. The camera shows her get close to her fingers, then cuts away as she keeps chopping.
The film took place in modern times. As for the plot, I can't really tell. I only saw this one scene. I remember the actors all being Asian, and I remember it being a foreign language film. I am relatively confident it was a Japanese horror film. As for the actors' looks, I don't remember much. I kind of remember a tan/white sweater being a part of the scene, but I am really not confident in that.
I know this is vague, but if anyone can help me find this I would be very grateful. 

Hi. Do you remember anything about the actual plot, however vague? Or maybe what the actress looked like? Or when the film took place (Modern times)?

@Walt Film took place in modern times. As for the plot, I can't really tell you. I only saw this one scene. I remember the actors all being asian, and I remember it being a foreign language film. I am relatively confident it was a Japanese horror film. As for actor looks, I don't remember much. I kind of remember a tan/white sweater being a part of the scene, but I am really not confident in that.

Thanks, added. See this scene from the Japanese horror film Suicide Club (2001) [Warning: Very Graphic]. It might be what you're after.

@Walt not at all how I remembered it, but that's it alright.

OK, I put it up.

You're looking for the Japanese horror film Suicide Club from 2001.

In Tokyo, when fifty-four high-school students commit a collective suicide, jumping from a platform in Shinjuku Station, the police force leaded by Detective Kuroda has no clue to follow. Then he receives an e-mail from a young woman, The Bat, advising that there is a site where red dots mean the number of persons that died. Kuroda and his team investigate the deaths going nowhere.

In one of the scenes, a smiling mother slices her fingers off while preparing a meal for her daughter. Some of the scene can be seen here. (Warning: Gory!!)

